# "Verification failed" for OTA "April 2016 patches" on a Nexus 6P

Tags: ota-update, nexus-6p

I have a brand new Nexus 6P that gives me the following error when attempting to install the next OTA update.

[image: Error message: Android System Update Couldn't download...]

Clicking the "Check for update" button doesn't help.

I've tried a factory reset but that didn't change the situation.

How can I come past this point?

Comment: try a different Internet connection

Comment: I've tried multiple but your suggestion made me try again. This time over a VPN in a different country. It worked! Thanks.

Comment: posted as answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with a different Internet connection. That is often the problem.